# How to assign domain names to containers in Docker?

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose

I am reading a lot these days about how to setup and run a docker stack.  But one of the things I am always missing out on is how to setup that particular containers respond to access through their domain name and not just their container name using docker dns.

What I mean is, that say I have a microservice which is accessible externally, for example: users.mycompany.com, it will go through to the microservice container which is handling the users api

Then when I try to access the customer-list.mycompany.com, it will go through to the microservice container which is handling the customer lists

Of course, using docker dns I can access them and link them into a docker network, but this only really works for wanting to access container to container, but not internet to container.

Does anybody know how I should do that?  Or the best way to set that up.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

So, you need to use the concept of port publishing, so that a port from your container is accessible via a port from your host. Using this, you can can setup a simple *proxy_pass* from an *Nginx* that will redirect `users.mycompany.com` to `myhost:1337` (*assuming that you published your port to `1337`*)

So, if you want to do this, you'll need to setup your container to expose a certain port using:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 training/webapp # publish image port 5000 to host port 5000
```

You can then from your host *curl* your `localhost:5000` to access the container.

```
curl -X GET localhost:5000
```

If you want to setup a domain name in front, you'll need to have a webserver instance that allows you to *proxy_pass* your hostname to your container.

i.e. in *Nginx*:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name users.mycompany.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
  }
}
```

I would advise you to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/usingdocker/#/running-a-web-application-in-docker), and maybe check the [docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

Comment: I'm confused. If you haven't exposed port 80 via docker configs then how would nginx (inside the container) ever receive that request to proxy pass it along?

Comment: @HariHonor I had the same question. Either one should use `docker run -d -p 5000:5000` and `listen 5000;`, or use `docker run -d -p 5000:80` and `listen 80;`. Also a bit confusing that the first paragraph stats you want to publish to port `1337`, then its suddenly `5000`

Comment: I'd say this is a heavy solution for a single project and unsuitable with multiple projects because once you have multiple docker-compose's, nginx will not be able to connect to them due to being in a different network.

It's a decent attempt, but this is something that should have been solved in docker. Unfortunately, the more one uses docker the more one realises that it lacks practicality (you can see this for yourself with the amount of github issues closed as "could be nice but not our problem").

Comment: @HariHonor the NGINX configuration described here isn't for NGINX inside the docker. Rather, this is an NGINX outside the docker that serves as a proxy to the local docker port. As such, NGINX can listen to whatever port it wants.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a one solution with the nginx and docker-compose:

- **users.mycompany.com** is in nginx container on port 8097
- **customer-list.mycompany.com** is in nginx container on port 8098

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8097;

    
    root /root/for/users.mycompany.com
    
    ...
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8098;

    
    root /root/for/customer-list.mycompany.com
    
    ...
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    
    server_name users.mycompany.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8097;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    
    server_name customer-list.mycompany.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8098;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Docker compose configuration :

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: MY_nginx
    build:
      context: .docker/nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

For all I know, Docker doesn't provide this feature out of the box. But surely there are several workarounds here. In fact you need to deploy a DNS on your host that will distinguish the containers and resolve their domain names in dynamical IPs. So you could give a try to:

1. Deploy some of Docker-aware DNS solutions (I suggest you to use *SkyDNSv1* / *SkyDock*);
2. Configure your host to work with this DNS (by default *SkyDNS* makes the containers know each other by name, but the host is not aware of it);
3. Run your containers with explicit `--hostname` (you will probably use scheme `container_name.image_name.dev.skydns.local`)

You can skip step *#2* and run your browser inside container too. It will discover the web application container by hostname.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone uses Apache as a main web server and needs to proxy the domain name to a specific machine, you will need to follow the following setup:

```
# Enable Apache moduels [ proxy proxy_http ]
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

and then you will need to create a new `VirtualHost` to proxy the domain requests to a specific IP address

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:PORT>
    ServerName domain-name.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://IPADDRESS:PORT/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://IPADDRESS:PORT/
</VirtualHost>
```

please note that you MUST replace the previous placeholders PORT & IPADDRESS with the IP address for your docker instance which is mot likely will be 0.0.0.0 and the relative port