# Docker: how to set a custom domain name for container?

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, ip

I'm deploying with Docker a PHP server available at localhost:8085.

How can I set Docker so that my container is available at a custom domain name (https://example.com) on my local network?

In result, every user connected to the same WiFi network would access to the server using the URL https://example.com (pointing to localhost:8085).

Comment: First of all you need a webserver (eg NGINX) to listen on port 80 and then forward to port 8085. You can run that in docker as well. Then you would need to configure your local dns to map the domain. Maybe your wifi router supports this already?

Comment: There’s nothing special in Docker for this; you’d configure it the same way you’d configure it for a non-Docker server running on port 8085 on your host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign domain names to containers in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867727/how-to-assign-domain-names-to-containers-in-docker)

Comment: @Mihai how can I configure my router to do this?

Comment: @Aliz I haven't done this in a long time but from what I remember you can install a dns server on your network (dnsmasq or else). Then you can register the IP of the dns server on the router's web interface. You have to see if it makes sense to go through all this trouble based on the size of your network anyway.