# How to connect to a docker container using a domain name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I have some docker web application, when it loads using `docker-compose` the dhcp service chooses some ip address lets say `192.168.96.3`, the webapp is located at port `6000`, so connecting to the webapp I use `http://192.168.96.3:6000`. Is there any way, in the `docker-compose.yml` to assign the domain name `foo.local` so that when I connect to the webapp I type in `foo.local:6000`?

In my `docker-compose.yml`, can I add a domain name that my host machine can map to the dynamic ip of the container?

**Note:**
The container uses its own network, so attaching it to the host network will conflict with its purpose.

Comment: what OS are you running docker on?

Comment: How do you assign domain names to other processes running locally on your host?  [How to assign domain names to containers in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867727/how-to-assign-domain-names-to-containers-in-docker) discusses how to set this up using published ports and a reverse proxy; Compose won't do this out-of-Docker network setup on its own.

Comment: I am running arch linux os

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Forwarding container port**

For me you can easily accessing from the host by exposing the port of the container. So from that host you should be able to access it as localhost:6000 by exposing the port. From other machines in your network that can access the host, use the IP of the host or its name/DNS name.

For example in docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    myservice:
        image: myImage
        ports:
            - "published_port:container_port"
```

So if you put "6000:6000" its mean that on the host port 6000 will forward to the service on port 6000.

**DNS**

So I would say for overall access, ensure that your company DNS match foo.local to your docker host and expose the port from the container in docker to the docker host.

If you want to be able to do that only from a given machine yoythe host you can add an entry to /etc/hosts (assuming linux)

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       foo.local
```

Here this is assuming we are on the same machine, but you can use the right IP. And if you have a different OS, check the documentation on how to do that for your os.

Comment: The container makes its own network, so attaching it to host dose not work in this circumstance thank you though. The container uses a vpn so using the host network would conflict with its ability to be in its own vpn.

Comment: But actually you are right about the port forwarding on the host machine, that can work for me.

Comment: Container almost always use their own network, this is best practice, sometime even several. But if you publish the port (completely unrelated to the various network the container is part of) then the host machine publish that port too and docker forward it to the container (actually does load balancing between all instances of the service). I didn't say to use "host" networking in docker. Once the port is published on the docker host, associate a DNS entry to that host.